# Rdlc export to excel issue: when group is added with details

Tags: c#, rdlc, export-to-excel

Im having the rdlc where i need to show the tree structure i.e.,drill down.
   When im trying to export the same to excel its showing the error.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

But when i gone through this... I found out that the issue for this is the Group.
 which im adding to display the report in tree structure and as well i added the details data in the same group instead in details row. so that the whole report will display in the same page where we can see the toggle easily and looks good. Below i attached the xml code of the same.

[Please find the xml here](http://textsnip.com/30f69c)

so,Is there any solution for this..... when exporting to pdf its working fine but when im trying to export to excel its showing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im successful in finding out the real issue behind the export Problem.

Im hiding one of the column in the report as it is not needed to display in the report,But I didnt notice that the cell of this column is included in one of the merged cells that is a merged row.

so this is the problem,the cell which is hidden was under merged cells.

when im trying to export it is throwing an error. when it is removed from merged cell its working fine.